# Securing connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security

I need some advice on how to protect a SQL Server. I wish to know

1. there's a way to deny a user to create an odbc from excel to connect to it
2. there's a way to use private/public keys to authenticate to the server
3. there's a way to allow only particular application to connect to the server

I can add a firewall in front to filter IPs but I also wish to filter for the application.

Is there a way?

Thank you very much

Comment: 1. sure, don't give them a login. 2. Sure, use ipsec. 3. thiis impossible in all contexts

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no mechanism to securely block a given application to connect the way you seem to be trying to.

If the user has valid credentials for SQL server and the server is configured to accept remote connections from the client machine (i.e. the firewall allows the connection, etc.), the best assumption is that the client will be able to connect to SQL Server successfully.

The [logon trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) idea from Gary would be an effective mechanism to prevent abuse by limiting the number of concurrent sessions from a single user, and verifying the application name is a way to keep honest people honest, but be warned that the application name can be easily spoofed and it should not be used as a strong authentication/authorization mechanism.

SQL Server can authenticate itself to the client using TLS/SSL certificates, but not to authenticate the client. Even though it may not be a solution for your scenario, it is still recommended to use encrypted connections.

One more recommendation. The moment you expose a SQL Server to potentially hostile IPs, you can bet that there will be automated attempts to break into it by guessing the SA password. If possible, use Integrated authentication (Windows authentication) only, if not, I strongly recommend to rename and/or disable the SA account using [ALTER LOGIN DDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I hope this information helps,

-Raul Garcia

SQL Security

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 ways to authenticate to SQL Server:

1. Integrated Logins, i.e., you use your Windows credentials, or
2. Mixed Mode -- you can log in use either the windows login or you can log in using SQL server credentials via Name and Password.

You can create a [logon trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx), example from the article

```
CREATE TRIGGER connection_limit_trigger
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'login_test'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'login_test' AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
            WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND
                original_login_name = 'login_test') > 3
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

With the login trigger you can test for the application, etc. as desired and rollback if you wish to deny the logon attempt.

e.g. if app_name <> 'MyApp' then rollback the connection attempt.

Re: public/private keys, if using a VPN you will be using public/private keys in the VPN infrastruction. If you are simply connecting directly to the server over a standard socket you are simply using the SQL Server infrastructure directly, i.e., you have no control over public/private key usage. Likewise for IPsec.

SQL Server does have some support for public/private keys as well as symmetric keys, but this does not really have anything directly related to establishing a connection.

What you probably want is an [encrypted connection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which requires sql to use SSL (which includes pub/priv keys) for its connection. You configure the server to support encryption and force it to require SSL and only SSL connections will be allowed.